# CNTK Loss and Error Metric function for multi label classification

Tags: cntk

Other than squared_error what other loss function / error function would I be able to use ?

I looked through https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.losses.html 
and wasn't able to find anything that helps.

i found documentation for brain script but not in python

any help would be amazing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best source of documentation (IMHO) is [python documentation](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/). If you need to write your own loss function I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132048/cntk-define-a-custom-loss-function-s%C3%B8rensen-dice-coefficient) very helpful. Try using sigmoid function at the output layer and binary cross entropy loss or cosine loss.

```
target = cntk.input_variable(input_dim)
loss = cntk.binary_cross_entropy(z, target)
```

This way your nodes will output probabilities independent of each other like [0.73, 0.02, 0.05, 0.26, 0.68].

Answer (score 0):

For multi-class classification, we typically use [cross_entropy_with_softmax](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.losses.html#cntk.losses.cross_entropy_with_softmax).

You are trying to attribute 2 or more class to every sample, then there's no native implementation in cntk

Comment: I don't cntk has a built in category_cross_entropy_with_softmax ? .. i couldn't find it in the documentation or in the code

Comment: its in the python API, not too sure about brainscript. I updated the answer with the link

Comment: Oh yes but correct me if i am worng but that one is mainly for one hot encoded target ... from their example I would ideally want -  C.cross_entropy_with_softmax([[1., 1., 50., 50.]], [[0., 0., 1., 1.]]).eval()    ...... to result in 0.    ..... but it would say 50  ( array([[-49.30685425]], dtype=float32) ).

Comment: For classification problems, you must one hot encode.

Comment: i don't think you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: Oh, i think i got it. You are trying to attribute 2 or more class to every sample is it? Then there's no naive implementation in cntk.

Comment: Yeap!!! that is exatly it .... that is a bummer ... i guess i will try out C.squared_error and start looking in to how to implement my own